# How to swap the vowles between in the strings

Tags: python, string

I have string

`hello` the vowels has to swap and the output is `holle` `e` and `o` is swapped

Below is my code

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

first_str = 'aiao'
l = list(first_str)
vowel_list = []
for vowel in l :
    if vowel in vowels:
        vowel_list.append(vowel)
for index,value in enumerate(l):
    if value in vowels:
#         print(value)
        l[index] = vowel_list[-1]
        vowel_list.remove(vowel_list[-1]) 
        print(vowel_list)
''.join(l)
```

I got output `oaai` Expected is also `oaia`

My Approach

1. extract all vowels in list
2. iterate over the string
3. Swap the vowels while iterating from right side by putting [-1]
4. After swap remove the element from the vowels list

edit courtesy @pranav using pop code is working ine

```
for index,value in enumerate(l):
    if value in vowels:
        l[index] = vowel_list.pop(-1)
''.join(l)
```

Comment: `vowel_list.remove(vowel_list[-1])` doesn't do what you expect if that list has duplicate elements. Maybe you meant to use `pop()`?

Comment: Also please specify the logic behind that expected output from that input

Comment: @PranavHosangadi why its not working with duplicate elements as i m removing the index. also pop is working

Comment: @abd `remove()` method removes the first occurrence of the specified element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go**

```
vowels = "aeiou"
str = 'aiao'
str = list(str)

i = 0 ; j = len(str)-1

while i < j:
    while i<j and str[i] not in vowels:
        i += 1
    while i<j and str[j] not in vowels:
        j -= 1
    str[i], str[j] = str[j], str[i]
    i += 1
    j -= 1

print("".join(str))
```

**Approach : (Two Pointer Approach)**

1. Set two pointers(start and end of the string)
2. Move the pointer until you find vowel
3. Swap the characters at the pointers
4. Repeat this until the pointers cross each other

Hope this solution helps

Comment: not in v:, what is v here? vowels

Comment: Yes. Updated now